# exif_imagetype() [function.exif-imagetype]:

Tags: php, file-upload, exif

hi all when Using exif_imagetype() [function.exif-imagetype]: function for checking images if the user hits the submit button without uploading anything the exif function returns an error in the webpage itself. my question is how to get rid of this error. am pasting the error below

```
Warning: exif_imagetype() [function.exif-imagetype]: Filename cannot be empty in /mounted-    storage/home98a/sub009/sc61374-HGPS/sitakalyanam.com/newsita/php4upload.class.php on line 88
```

```
 <?php
 /*

 - PHP4 Image upload script

  */

   class imageupload
   {
//pblic variables
var $path = '';
var $errorStr = '';
var $imgurl = '';

        //private variables
  var $_errors = array();
  var $_params = array();
  var $_lang = array();
  var $_maxsize = 1048576;

    var $_im_status = false;

    //public methods
    function imageupload ()
    {
        //require 'photouploadconfig.php';

 if($_GET['Choice']=="1")
  {             
  require 'Photouploddir1.php';
  }
  elseif ($_GET['Choice']=="2")
  {
  require 'Photouploddir2.php';
 }
 elseif ($_GET['Choice']=="3")
 {
 require 'Photouploddir3.php';
 }
 elseif ($_GET['horoschoice']=="1")
 {
require 'horosuploaddir.php';
}
elseif ($_GET['videoChoice']=="5")
{
require 'videouploaddir.php';
}  


        $this->_types = $types;
    $this->_lang = $lang;
        $this->_upload_dir = $upload_dir;
        $this->_maxsize = $maxsize;

        $this->path = $PHP_SELF;


        if (is_array($_FILES['__upload']))
        {
            $this->_params = $_FILES['__upload'];
            if (function_exists('exif_imagetype'))
                $this->_doSafeUpload();
            else
                $this->_doUpload();

            if (count($this->_errors) > 0)
                $this->_errorMsg();
        }
    }

    function allowTypes ()
    {
        $str = '';
        if (count($this->_types) > 0) {
            $str = 'Allowed types: (';
            $str .= implode(', ', $this->_types);
            $str .= ')';
        }

        return $str;
    }

    // private methods

    function _doSafeUpload ()
    {

         preg_match('/\.([a-zA-Z]+?)$/', $this->_params['name'], $matches);
          if (exif_imagetype($this->_params['tmp_name']) && in_a    rray(strtolower($matches[1]), $this->_types))
        {
            if ($this->_params['size'] > $this->_maxsize)
                $this->_errors[] = $this->_lang['E_SIZE'];
            else
                $this->_im_status = true;

            if ($this->_im_status == true)
            {
                $ext = substr($this->_params['name'], -4);
                $this->new_name = md5(time()).$ext;

                move_uploaded_file($this->_params['tmp_name'], $this->_up     load_dir.$this->new_name);

            $this->imgurl =$this->new_name;

            //$this->imgurl = .$this->new_name;


            }
        }
        else

        $this->_errors[] = $this->_lang['E_TYPE'];
    }

    function _doUpload ()
    {
        preg_match('/\.([a-zA-Z]+?)$/', $this->_params['name'], $matches);
        if(in_array(strtolower($matches[1]), $this->_types))
        {
            if ($this->_params['size'] > $this->_maxsize)
                $this->_errors[] = $this->_lang['E_SIZE'];
            else
                $this->_im_status = true;

            if ($this->_im_status == true)
            {
                $ext = substr($this->_params['name'], -3);
                $this->new_name = md5(time()).$ext;

                move_uploaded_file($this->_params['tmp_name'], $this-    >_upload_dir.$this->new_name);

                $this->imgurl = ''.$this->new_name;

        //$this->imgurl = ''.$this->_upload_dir.''.$this->new_name;
        //$this->imgurl = ''.$this->new_name;

                //$this->imgurl = $this->_upload_dir.'/'.$this->new_name;



            }
        }
        else
            $this->_errors[] = $this->_lang['E_TYPE'];
    }

    function _errorMsg()
    {

        $this->errorStr = implode('<br />', $this->_errors);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: What is `$this->_params`?

Comment: wait i will add my entier code now

Comment: Wait.  So, if the user doesn't select a file, this gives an error?  Can't you just check if `empty($this->_params['tmp_name'])`?

Comment: i have checked and i have pasted the entire code here . yes you are right if the user dosent select any file for uploading then it displays the error in the webpage itself at the user end. you mean to say ...  if(empty($this->_params['tmp_name']){print "<script>";
       print " self.location='modifyphoto.php';"; // Comment this line if you don't want to redirect
       print "</script>";}

Comment: If a file isn't uploaded `$_FILES` *should* be an empty array.  So, just check that: `if(count($_FILES) === 0){ echo "no file uploaded"; }`

Comment: i am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting T_FUNCTION if i an using if(count($_FILES) === 0){ echo "no file uploaded"; }

Comment: Where are you putting that?

Comment: hooo i thing i pasted inside the class definition

Comment: It needs to go inside a function, not just inside the class.

Comment: no hope i pasted that inside function _doSafeUpload (){ but still getting the error

Comment: wow its working now i pasted it in function imageupload ()
 {
 if(count($_FILES) === 0){ echo "no file uploaded"; } Rocket Hazmat you are a genius

Comment: how can i vote for you.. tell me how to vote for you

Comment: I added my suggestion as an actual answer.  You can vote on it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that message because you are never checking if the user uploaded a file or not, you're just assuming they are.  When the user does not upload a file then `$_FILES` will be an empty array.

That means that `$this->_params['tmp_name']` won't exist.  You need to check if a file was uploaded, not just assume one was.

Just simply check the size of `$_FILES`.

```
if(count($_FILES) === 0){
    echo "no file uploaded";
}
```

Comment: bad news the error is comming again i have pasted the code in the following manner //public methods
 function imageupload ()
 {
 if(count($_FILES) === 0)
 { echo "no file uploaded";}

Comment: @shijumax: Well, you need to do something if there is no file uploaded.  The `echo` was just an example.

Comment: i tried alert and redirect using print function everything is happening exept the error displayed in the user end sustains its not vanishing

Comment: @shijumax: You need to stop the PHP script.  After that `if` runs, it continues on.  Try to add `exit;` after the code in the `if`.

Comment: i want to supress the error getting displayed how to do that any idea on your side ???

Comment: You don't want to suppress the error.  You want to check for it, and do the correct action.

Comment: @shijumax: Are you still having trouble?

Comment: very worried sir actually i have three files linked to gether and if i put redirect on error its creating a loop and the web page just keeps on refresing again and again which is no good do you have an email id can you help me with this any help will be greatley appreciated

Comment: Try adding a GET flag.  Like redirect to `page.php?redirect=1`.  Then on each page check for that flag, and if it's set don't redirect.

Comment: hmm i will try ;-(  actually i am new to php in learning stage and its giving me more stress will try hazmat

Comment: @shijumax: You can try asking a new question (or editing this one) if you're having troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this one and then try

```
    if (isset($_FILES['__upload']))
    {
        $this->_params = $_FILES['__upload'];
        if (function_exists('exif_imagetype'))
            $this->_doSafeUpload();
        else
            $this->_doUpload();

        if (count($this->_errors) > 0)
            $this->_errorMsg();
    }
```